# Programatic subscription to AWS Marketplace image

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-marketplace

hope everyone is fit and well !!

So this time i'm trying to launch some AWS Marketplace images using cloudformation and terraform both and it works fine on my account as i have already subscribed to these images, but it doesnt work on other account as these are not been subscribed there.

I'm looking for some way of either accepting or opting for subscription via automation ( any api or command ) and get these instances launched without fail.

i dont know if at all it is possible to create custome images from these marketplace image so that subscription can be avoided , please suggest

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

This functionality can be achieved via

**Option#1**: via AWS SDK like Go:

`I. aws_licensemanager_grant`

[CreateGrant](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/licensemanager/#LicenseManager.CreateGrant)

[DeleteGrant](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/licensemanager/#LicenseManager.DeleteGrant)

[GetGrant](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/licensemanager/#LicenseManager.GetGrant)

`II. aws_licensemanager_license_grants data source`

[ListDistributedGrants](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/licensemanager/#LicenseManager.ListDistributedGrants)

`III. aws_licensemanager_grant_version`

[CreateGrantVersion](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/licensemanager/#LicenseManager.CreateGrantVersion)

`IV. aws_licensemanager_grant_accepter`

[AcceptGrant](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/licensemanager/#LicenseManager.AcceptGrant)

[ListReceivedGrants](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/licensemanager/#LicenseManager.ListReceivedGrants)

[RejectGrant](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/licensemanager/#LicenseManager.RejectGrant)

---

**Option#2**: via `terraform`, using the Terraform AWS Provider [v4.58.0](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/blob/v4.58.0/CHANGELOG.md)

**Resources:**

[aws_licensemanager_grant](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/licensemanager_grant) 一 Allow sharing a license with another account.

[aws_licensemanager_grant_accepter](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/licensemanager_grant_accepter) 一 Accepting a shared license in the target account.

**Datasources:**

[aws_licensemanager_received_license](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/licensemanager_received_license) 一 A data source to get detailed data about an accepted AWS License from the market place.

[aws_licensemanager_received_licenses](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/licensemanager_received_licenses) 一 A data source to get a list of ARNs for accepted AWS market place licenses that match a filter.

[aws_licensemanager_grants](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/licensemanager_grants) 一 A data source to get a list of grant ARNs for the account matching a filter.